# what is convergence in k Means?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, unsupervised-learning

I have a very small question related to unsupervised learning because my teacher have not use this word in any lectures. I got this word while reading tutorials. Does this mean if values are same to initial values in last iteration of clusters then it is called converge? for example

```
      |  c1   |  c2  | cluster
      | (1,0) | (2,1)|
      |-------|------|------------
A(1,0)| ..    |..    |get smallest value
B(0,1)|..     |...   |
c(2,1)|..     |...   |
D(2,1)|..     |....  |
```

now after performing n-iteration and if values come same in both c1 and c2 that is (1,0) and (2,1) in last n-th iteration and taking avg if other than single , is it convergence?

Comment: This sounds more like a general CS question, not a programming question, so would probably be more appropriate at cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, if the values in the last two consequent iterations are same then the algorithm is said to have converged. But often people use a less strict criteria for convergence, like, the difference in the values of last two iterations is less than a particular threshold etc,.

Comment: thnx. but sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Incase of K-means clustering, the word convergence means  the algorithm have successfully completed this clustering or grouping of data points in k number of clusters.The algorithm will make sure it has completely grouped the data points into correct clusters, if the centroids (k values) in k-means remains same place or in point for 2 iteration .